# increasing and decreasing the number of tabs in tabBarcontroller ios

Tags: ios, tabs

i have created tabs using tabBarcontroller.

oringnally my code was written for the number of tabs to be fixed to 5.

now i need to change the number of tabs to be unfixed and can vary from lets say 1 to 5.

the decision lies with the user who can change the values in a server.

each time i load the view in tab the synchronisation with server data happens.

so at this point the user can decide to go from 5 to 3 tabs. and on next tab press from 3 to 4

how do i increase and decrease the number of tabs on tab press

Answer (score 1):

[[UITabBar setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBar/setItems%3aanimated%3a)

You'll have to manage the array manually, and use the UITabBarControllerDelegate methods if you want to do it on selection of a tab.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you could manage the `UITabbarController` tab by accessing it like so:

```
NSMutableArray *myViewControllersInTabBar = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
```

To remove:

```
[myViewControllersInTabBar removeObjectAtIndex:<INDEX_OF_CONTROLLER_YOU_WISH_TO_REMOVE];
```

To add:

```
[myViewControllersInTabBar insertObject:<CONTROLLER_TO_ADD> atIndex:<INDEX_NUMBER>];
```

Then:

```
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:myViewControllersInTabBar];
```

To get notification when a tab is selected, conform to `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and implement the methods.

One of these being:

```
– tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

Here is a to a list of `UITabBarControllerDelegate`'s delegate methods:

[UITabBarControllerDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope this helps.